# Selecting/Uploading Obb file in new Developer Console

Tags: android, google-developers-console

As Google has forced us to use new developer console with no option to switch to old one, I am unable to find a way to select an obb file, or upload a new one.

[image]

Comment: Note that use of obb expansion files has been superseded by [Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery) as per the [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/introducing-google-play-asset-delivery.html).

Comment: your comment was helpful but things don't just disappear like that, the option is back now after contacting google. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Google using support email and after half a month, they fixed this, and option to upload/select obb is here now.

just click the three dots right in front of uploaded apk and you will see the option to upload obb, in that dialog you can select already uploaded obb by select add from library.

[image]

Comment: I still cant see the option

Comment: for old app that has been already using obb, they can still upload obb when uploading an apk file, but new apps dont have that option.